# Docker - check within the container if a directory is mounted from the host or not

Tags: docker

I have a need to check if a directory **in my running container** is mounted from the host or not.
Example: using the `docker run .... -v /host-data:/data ....` command.

If not mounted, I want to warn the user that data on this directory will be lost when the container is terminated...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a rough, but simple solution.

```
mount | grep '/data'
```

will result in **0** if found (which means it's mounted).
I added it to my entry-point script and it works as expected.

Ideas for improvements are welcome!

I hope this helps.

Comment: This is brilliant and so very simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
   mountVar=`mount | grep "$BLA"`
   if [ -z "$mountVar" ]
   then
      echo "$BLA not mounted  exit"
      exit
   else      
      echo "$BLA  mounted "

   fi
```